# Placing Variables into an external Sheet

Tags: javascript, php, html, external

Trying to Build an Online D&d program which stores the character info into Tables my problem is the game works just fine while your playing but as soon as you exit game all varibles are lost which means you have to restart from scratch the next time you log on...
So this is a Two Fold Question
What is the Best type of External Sheet to save it on...
and two How to access sheet for saving and Loading

Below are Varibles

```
<SCRIPT>
Name1="Tabor Bloomfield";
Name2="Sam Wrightfield";
Name3="Gavin Hartfild";
Name4="Gail Quickfoot";
Name5="Robert Gragorian";
Name6="Peter Shain";
Class1="MagicUser";
Class2="Fighter";
Class3="Fighter";
Class4="Thief";
Class5="Cleric";
Class6="Fighter";
Level1=23;
Level2=1;
Level3=1;
Level4=2;
Level5=2;
Level6=1;
Hpts1=145;
Hpts2=14;
Hpts3=13;
Hpts4=8;
Hpts5=12;
Hpts6=15;
Armor1="Robe of Protection +5";
Armor2="Splinted Armor";
Armor3="Chain Armor";
Armor4="Leather Armor";
Armor5="Chain Armor";
Armor6="Splinted Armor";
Ac1a=5;
Ac2a=3;
Ac3a=3;
Ac4a=4;
Ac5a=2;
Ac6a=3;
Armor1b="Ring of Protection +5";
Armor2b="Small Shield";
Armor3b="Small Shield";
Armor4b="Wooden Shield";
Armor5b="Large Shield";
Armor6b="Small Shield";
Ac1b=5;
Ac2b=1;
Ac3b=1;
Ac4b=1;
Ac5b=1;
Ac6b=1;
Str1=21;
Str2=16;
Str3=14;
Str4=13;
Str5=14;
Str6=13;
Int1=19;
Int2=11;
Int3=12;
Int4=13;
Int5=14;
Int6=13;
Wis1=18;
Wis2=12;
Wis3=14;
Wis4=13;
Wis5=14;
Wis6=12;
Dex1=19;
Dex2=14;
Dex3=13;
Dex4=15;
Dex5=14;
Dex6=12;
Con1=19;
Con2=15;
Con3=16;
Con4=13;
Con5=12;
Con6=10;
Chr1=21;
Chr2=14;
Chr3=13;
Chr4=12;
Chr5=14;
Chr6=13;
</SCRIPT>
```

---

```
File name ="gamestats"
Path="trellian Webpage/droves E and F/gamestats
```

have tryed html Page,Javascript,Creating a serperate table page and putting the varibles into cells...But at a lost on how to arrive at a solution

Comment: You *really* need to learn what arrays are...

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide more details than that Leslie. What programming language? what env? more detailed description of how the variables are stored (in Javascript memory, in a DB...?) and how your logout process works. Narrow it down first :)

Comment: Working mainly with Java and Html mostly Working on learning PHP
My sytem is a dell computer running on Windows Xp...Trying to keep it web based as much as possible...Going to put Varibles into Arrays as suggested by Zaf below that will cut down on Space but still doesnt tell me how to save the arrays to an external sheet

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to either use something like Google Gears with local storage, or use a server side language like PHP or ASP.Net to store those values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PHP, I recommend you use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) database layer with [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).  There is plenty of documentation for all three.

Comment: No where the TS mentions PHP. It's javascript what he uses.

Comment: Actually, the OP tagged the question PHP, and said he's learning it.

Answer (score 0):

OK - lets say the  tags imply you're using javascript in a html page.

It's best if you start using arrays. More info here:
http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_obj_array.asp

Then you can use ajax to submit this array full of values to the a PHP script which saves this to a database. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Also, at the start of a game you can have a PHP script which reads from the database and creates the array.

Thats the basics of doing it one particular way.

Comment: Thanks Zaf I will start there and let you see what I come up With